# Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am thinking the leetcode question 167, but get a problem `Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)` with my code.
below is my c code, and the expected answer is [1,3].

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/**
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* numbers, int numbersSize, int target, int* returnSize) {

    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<numbersSize;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<numbersSize;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i]+numbers[j]==target)
                {
                    *returnSize = 2;
                     int *indexes = malloc(*returnSize * sizeof(int));
                     indexes[0] = i + 1;
                     indexes[1] = j + 1;
                     return indexes;
                }
        }
    }
    *returnSize = 0;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={2,3,4};
    int *a;
    int *p=twoSum(arr,3,6,a);
    printf("%d,%d",*p,*(p+1));

    return 0;
}
```

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Mk0sgwTsZf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `a` is not initialized, you can call *malloc* function to allocate memory or pass pointer to local `int a` variable

```
int a;
int *p=twoSum(arr,3,6,&a);
```

second, your `twoSum` function can return NULL value, so you should add the condition to check this return value if it is not NULL

```
int a;
int *p=twoSum(arr,3,6,&a);
if(p)
    printf("%d,%d",*p,*(p+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it is, in your `main()`, you have `int * a;` but you never made it point to a valid memory, the content is *indeterminate*.

Later, you pass it to the function as argument, receive it in parameter `returnSize` and try to dereference that. Essentially you're dereferencing an invalid memory which leads to undefined behavior.

Then, when your call to function `twoSum()` returns a `NULL`, you must not go ahead and derererefnce the returned pointer. You should put a check for non-NULL value of the returned pointer and use the `printf()` call, (which dereference the returned pointer) conditionally.